# Windows 10 Free Upgrade - What happens to Windows 7/8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10-upgrade, license

Microsoft is giving Windows 10 away for free to Windows 7/8/8.1 users. If one reserves Windows 10 with the new notification in the tray area, what will happen to their Windows 7/8/8.1 license?

Are you really getting Windows 10 for free, as in you upgrade from 7/8/8.1 but you still own the previous version of Windows and Windows 10, or are you really trading your old Windows license for a new one?

Basically, after upgrading to Windows 10 for free from Windows 7, will I still own Windows 7? (Will the product key for 7 still work?)

Comment: Microsoft has not said one way or another.  In the past the way similar programs work, both licenses could still be used, just one was technically invalid.  The way the free Windows 8.1 w/Media Center upgrade work is a really good indication how we will claim our Windows 10 licenses, you purchased the upgrade for $0.0 , and were sent an email which contained a valid Windows 8.1 w/ Media Center license which was independant of the original Windows 8.1 license.

Comment: The "duplicate" question 486959 doesn't have an applicable answer here.  But section 7 of the EULA (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm) does seem to talk about downgrade rights for Professional versions.

Comment: I'm mixed on the duplicate-ness of the question, but I do seem to think this and the other questions are more about licencing than computers, and well, isn't entirely on topic. I'm inclined to leave it closed, as such.

Answer (score 4):

It is absolutely clear. After you have upgraded, there is no downgrade "right" though doubtless you can continue on 7/8 at least for a while.

Certainly if you are asking will the 7/8 license ALSO be valid at the same time - it will not. It is replaced entirely.

Comment: So if I upgrade and try to use my old Windows 7 key on another computer, it will not work?

Comment: Correct, it will have been replaced. The old license is no longer valid.

Comment: @JulianKnight - Where has Microsoft stated, that the license used to claim the free Windows license, will cease to work entirely?  Because from personal experience with the free Media Center upgrade, I ended up with two licenses that could be activated.

Comment: Mediacentre is very different to Windows itself. The only reason they are making this offer to people not on enterprise subscriptions is to try and kill off Windows 7/8 as quickly as possible so they can focus on 10. They are notoriously tight-lipped about Licensing which is an industry in itself but I've been working very closely with them recently & their intent is clear.

Comment: @JulianKnight - What kind of formal evidence do you have?  If you are saying that Windows 10 will accept and activate with Windows 7 and WIndows 8.1 key I might accept that explaination.  My conclusion to how the upgrade process will work is entirely different, I suspect and my past experiences support this, is that come July 29th 2015 you will literally "purchase" a Windows 10 license for $0.00 using a similar tool that was used to order Windows 8 and the Media Center upgrade.  I will continue this discussion in the chatroom shortly.

Comment: As I've said, Microsoft are not publishing "evidence". This upgrade is different to anything previous. They want rid of W7/8. I cannot absolutely guarantee that it won't work differently since I am not Microsoft. We will see wont we.

Comment: Information is now published for those who didn't believe. You have 30d to downgrade after that you cannot.

Comment: @JulianKnight 
 
Actually, those 30 days are just because of the temporary files are being removed to save space. The Windows 7/8 license is perfectly fine. The upgrade appears to let you have 2 unrelated licenses, so it doesn't replace the 7/8 key, but rather just gives you a new license for 10.

Comment: @JulianKnight 
 
If you try downgrading to your old Windows after 30 days using installation media, it should activate fine with the old key.