# What will happen if i update a dual boot windows 7 to windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows

I m wondering that what will happen if I update windows 7 to windows 10 in pc where windows 10 already installed but not activated, I want to do this cuz my windows 7 is activated and I don't want to buy windows 10(side note ms still giving free update to Windows 10 until 31st Dec) and which edition of win 10 will i get i have win 7 ultimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which edition of Windows 10 will I get if I have Windows 7 Ultimate?

Windows 10 Professional

> I want to do this because my Windows 7 is activated and I don't want
> to buy Windows 10

The free upgrade offer expired back on July 29th.  You would be only eligible for the current offer, which is only valid if you use assistive technologies, which of course expired on December 31 2017.

> We're committed to making sure customers using assistive technologies
> can upgrade to Windows 10. For more info about the free upgrade offer
> for customers using assistive technologies, see Accessibility and the
> Windows 10 free upgrade.
>
> Note: The accessibility upgrade offer expires
> on December 31, 2017.

[Upgrade to Windows 10: FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12435/windows-10-upgrade-faq)

> I am wondering that what will happen if I update Windows 7 to Windows
> 10

If you upgrade your Windows 7 installation to Windows 10, then you will be left with an activated Windows 10 Professional installation, and inactivated copy of an unknown edition of Windows 10.

Comment: I did my best to answer this question.  "What will happen" is an extremely odd question to answer, because what happens if you perform the upgrade is sort of obvious so it's not entirely clear what the actual question is.  *I encourage the author of the question to clarify their question.*

Comment: Relevant: [Windows 10 Free Upgrade - What happens to Windows 7/8?](https://superuser.com/questions/922867/windows-10-free-upgrade-what-happens-to-windows-7-8?rq=1) and [What happens to the Windows 7 key when upgrading to Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/486959/what-happens-to-the-windows-7-key-when-upgrading-to-windows-8?rq=1).  Although the original free offer expired back on July 29th, the existing answers on the subject, apply to the current offer.

Comment: First of all, thanks that were some good explanation to my noob question, and what my main moto to ask this question was what will happen to my currently installed window 10 and its apps and files and mainly what about boot manager

Comment: @ShantnuChaubey - If you are worried just activate that installation instead.  Just change the product key.  Of course technically you would be violating the spirit of the free upgrade offer.  I suspect you already plan to do that, since I am going to guess, you don't use assistive technologies.  Otherwise the existing Windows 10 installation wouldn't be touched.